# How can I display a page only when all its components have been fully loaded? - Oracle Apex

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I have a page that contains many components, for example one of them is region display selector and has the option: Include 'Show All' disabled, however when loading the page it is possible to display the items that should appear only in the second region of the region display selector and so on with the other regions that confirm the selector, I have also noticed that some fields that are hidden are displayed at the beginning while the page loads, how can I avoid this?
[image]

I have noticed that oracle apex page designer has it, how could I achieve something similar? I have searched the internet but I can't find a solution, thanks.
[image]

I only have validations with javascript in page load DA
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had success in eliminating the moment you see a momentary flash of secondary regions by applying a class with the `display:none` attribute to the regions not initially displayed.
[image: CSS region attribute]